# Spherical Harmonics Sum Identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, spherical-harmonics, special-functions

I'm taking a course in Quantum Mechanics and this problem is causing me some struggles. Can anyone help me to prove this identity?

$$\sum_{m = -l}^l m^2 |Y_{l}^{m}(\theta, \phi)|^2 = \frac{l(l+1)(2l+1)}{8\pi}\sin^2(\theta).$$

I had the idea to use addition theorem for the same $\theta$ and $\phi$ given by
$$\sum_{m = -l}^l |Y_{l}^{m}(\theta, \phi)|^2  = \frac{(2l+1)}{4\pi}.$$
Also I tried to use some recurrence relation for Legendre polynomials and induction on $l$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the process of proving the sum rule
\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=-l}^l |Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)|^2 = \frac{2l+1}{4\pi} \, ,
\end{equation}
you often start from the more general addition theorem for the spherical harmonics
\begin{equation}
P_l(\cos\gamma) = \frac{4\pi}{2l+1} \sum_{m=-l}^l Y_l^{m*}(\theta',\phi')Y_l^m(\theta,\phi) \, ,
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\cos\gamma = \cos\theta \cos\theta' + \sin\theta \sin\theta' \cos(\phi - \phi') \, .
\end{equation}
If you take this addition theorem, operate on both sides with $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}$, and then take the limit $(\theta', \phi') \rightarrow (\theta, \phi)$, then you reproduce the result for your sum.